# how to send email at backend of application in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email

hi
I want to send an email when user open the application but that email should be sent at back end so that user can not judge that application send an email.
any body can help me?
thanx

Comment: Entirely depends on your server technology, which you don't mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanx to all of you, all of you helped me & all of you are right but i find a simple way to send an email.

The easiest way to do this thing is to write a small script on php that sends a mail & upload it on your hosting & just hit it whenever u need. You will hit the URL & it will send an email.
Simple :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is for the purpose of simply knowing that someone ran the program, I would check out www.Flurry.com, free analytics for your app and very easy to integrate. (I have no connection with Flurry except as a user.)

Sending e-mail behind the scenes is not hard, necessarily, but you have to basically establish a network connection to a server that has a mail server (MTA), and then you have to "speak" SMTP to it, and a whole lot of things can go wrong in the process. :-) (I spent 10 years writing e-mail servers, so I know of what I speak. :-)

Check out Flurry. :-)

Comment: hmmmm thats good to use flurry i'll use it in my own projects but i think here 2nd option would be better :-)

Comment: Google Analytics might also be useful for the purpose. You can use it as part of the GData ObjC library, see: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

Comment: I think Google paralytics would be a big thing cz client's requirement is only to send an email on a specific address.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a third party library for that. The SDK doesn't allow you to send emails in the background.

Here's one you can use:
http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/

Comment: is it a requirement that it does not use a server?

Comment: its not a requirement but currently i m not using server